# Vector norms and equality

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove If norm(A+B) = Norm(B) then A= 0 Is the zero vector. Here norm is Euclidean norm and A and b are vectors in $R^n$

My attmept.

If $|\textbf{x}+\textbf{y}|= |\textbf{x}|$ for some vectors $\textbf{x},\textbf{y}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ then $\textbf{y} = 0$.  Note that \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
|\textbf{x}+\textbf{y}| &= |\textbf{x}|\\
& \Updownarrow\\
|\textbf{x}+\textbf{y}|^2 &= |\textbf{x}|^2\\ 
& \Updownarrow\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i+y_i)^2}  &= \sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i^2} \\
& \Updownarrow\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i^2+y_i^2)} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}{2x_i y_i} &= \sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i^2} \\
& \Updownarrow\\
 \sum_{i=1}^{n}{y_i^2 + 2x_i y_i} &=  0 \\
 & \Updownarrow\\
|\textbf{y}|^2 + 2\textbf{y}\cdot \textbf{x}&= 0\\
 & \Updownarrow\\
|\textbf{y}|^2  +2|\textbf{y}|\cdot |\textbf{x}| \cos(\varphi) & = 0\\
 & \Updownarrow\\
|\textbf{y}|\biggl(|\textbf{y}|  +2\cdot |\textbf{x}| \cos(\varphi)\biggr) & = 0\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
This occurs if and only if $|\textbf{y}| = 0$ or else $\biggl(|\textbf{y}|  +2\cdot |\textbf{x}| \cos(\varphi)\biggr) = 0$. We want to show that $\biggl(|\textbf{y}|  +2\cdot |\textbf{x}| \cos(\varphi)\biggr) \neq 0$ or else $|\textbf{y}| = \lambda |\textbf{x}|$ and $|\textbf{x}+\textbf{y}|= |\textbf{x}|$ would then not make since as \begin{equation}
|\textbf{x}+\textbf{y}|\le |\textbf{x}|+|\textbf{y}| = |\textbf{x}| + \lambda |\textbf{x}| = (1+\lambda)|\textbf{x}|\le |\textbf{x}|
\end{equation}
so $$|\textbf{x}+\textbf{y}|\le |\textbf{x}|$$
and so $\textbf{y} = \textbf{0}$ is the only solution.

Comment: please clarify your attempt. Thanks.

Comment: The claim need not be true.

Comment: Counterexample: $b = (1,0)$ and $a=(-2,0)$.

Comment: I tried but it seems not true